# Google Play Services sign in not working well on Unity Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

I'm trying to add Google Play Services on my Unity Android project.
I've got already implement google play services plugin to my project. Filling the all crediantials. I've got 2 different internal test accounts on developer console.

Here is my question:

- Account A: SignInStatus Success and not showing welcome pop-up
  message.
- Account B: SignInStatus Canceled and not sign in.

Is it because internal test or something?

unity version: 2019.4.16f1

gpgs plugin verison: 0.11.01

Here is my code:
referanced: https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity

```
using GooglePlayGames;
private bool Authenticated;

public void Start() {
  PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(ProcessAuthentication);
}

internal void ProcessAuthentication(SignInStatus status) {
  if (status == SignInStatus.Success) {
    // Continue with Play Games Services
    Authenticated = true;
  } else {
    // Disable your integration with Play Games Services or show a login button
    // to ask users to sign-in. Clicking it should call
    // PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.ManuallyAuthenticate(ProcessAuthentication).
    Authenticated = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your code.

I just created a new project, got a new SHA-1, added my account to the new google play console and verified that everything was tested successfully.

In doing so, we found the following problems:
If you are using the 11.01 version, please check if there is a problem by following the procedure below.

Follow the steps below to check.
(*Assets → External Dependency Manager → Android Resolver → Force Resolve*)

**Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml:11: Repo path 'Packages/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository' does not exist.**

If the above error occurs, you can solve it by choosing one of two solutions.

#### First, see comments by @greg-hanes [here](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/issues/3145).

The specific method is to create a GooglePlayGamesPluginDependencies.xml file inside the Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository folder and paste the following contents.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Internal library dependency generated at build time.
        It also defines the transitive dependencies on play-services
    -->
    <androidPackages>
        <androidPackage spec="com.google.games:gpgs-plugin-support:0.11.01">
            <repositories>
                <repository>Assets/GooglePlayGames/com.google.play.games/Editor/m2repository</repository>
            </repositories>
        </androidPackage>
    </androidPackages>
</dependencies>
```

And then Force Resolve again.
(**Gradle failed to fetch dependencies** on the way. If you get an error, make sure your JDK path is set correctly.)

#### Second, downgrade the version to version 10.14.

Here is my code that I wrote to run only once at runtime. It works successfully when I run it.

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using GooglePlayGames;
using GooglePlayGames.BasicApi;

public static class Login
{
  [RuntimeInitializeOnLoadMethod]
  public static void SignIn()
  {
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.Authenticate(success =>
    {
      Debug.Log(success ? "Success Login" : "Failed Login");
    });
  }
}
```

You can check the logs on Android by installing the Android Logcat package.

I hate the 11.01 version so I'm using the 10.14 version :)

Hope your problem is solved!

Comment: i tried your code with 10.14 version. and gives me error. status type boolean, signınStatus enum. 

callback: The callback to call when authentication finishes. It will be called with true if authentication was successful, false otherwise. How can i get status message ?

Comment: and i have a different question. Is showing admob ads for Signed in user  trusted?

Comment: @SalihTunçel ProcessAuthentication() is a callback method, if the conditional inside is Success, it succeeds, otherwise it fails. You can fork status messages accordingly. (Maybe I didn't understand the comment well..?)

Comment: @SalihTunçel **Google Play Game Services** and **admob** don't seem to have much to do with each other. We have confirmed that there is no problem in running Google Play Game Services and admob at the same time.

Comment: Social.localUser.Authenticate((success, message) => {}); worked for me

Comment: @SalihTunçel Are you referring to the success message when `Authenticate()` succeeds? You can specify it yourself using `Debug.Log()`.

Comment: @SalihTunçel sorry. My code works on version 11.01. Again, the code has been modified for version 10.14. Sorry again for the wrong test version.

Comment: Thank you sir, you've really saved me from a nightmare..